# Problems with sIFR Implementation - need help

Tags: sifr

I have 3 main problems with my sifr implementation . Has taken me 2 days of trying to fix without any tangible results.

1. cant get navigation lists to work in firefox.  I have followed all suggested fixes for this, including setting the replace on a higher level element - still doesnt work! here is my current code:

   sIFR.replace(louisiana, {
         selector: 'ul.tabs3 li'
         ,css: [ '.sIFR-root { font-size: 20px;}', 'a { color: #cc3333; text-decoration: none; padding:0px 8px; margin: 0;}', 'a:link { color: #555555; }', 'a:hover { color: #cc3333; }' ]
         ,thickness: 50
         ,wmode: 'transparent'
   });

it works in safari, but clicking on each navigational link is like an exercise in patience - extremely slow to load.

1. cant get content in jquery tabs to losd. only first tab works. I have read the proposed fixes about  using something like  the code below on the scrolling div - doesnt work for me.

   position: absolute;
   left: -10000px;

i have also come across a solution which says to use a call back function with my tab code. I have no idea how to do that. here is my tab code:

```
$(function() { 

    $("ul.tabs3").tabs("div.panes3 > div", 
                       {  history: true, 
                          current: 'current',
                        //  event:'mouseover',
                          effect: 'fade' 
                         });                                             
});
</script>
```

3. I cant get the code to exclude certain elements to be replaced to work. at the top of my config file I have:

   parseSelector.pseudoClasses = {
         'not': function(nodes, selector) {
           var result = [];
           each: for(var i = 0, node; i < nodes.length; i++) {
             node = nodes[i];
             var ignore = parseSelector(selector, node.parentNode);
             for(var j = 0; j < ignore.length; j++) {
               if(ignore[j] == node) continue each;
             }
             result.push(node);
           }
           return result;
         }
       }

and the replace code is :

```
sIFR.replace(louisiana, {
      selector: "h2, div:not(.filter) h2"
      ,css: '.sIFR-root { font-size: 30px; color: #444444; }'
      ,thickness: 70
      ,forceSingleLine: true
      ,wmode: 'transparent'
});
```

I really need help with this - have been going for 2 days and totally clueless at this point.

Answer (score 0):

sIFR shouldn't cause any slowdowns if you click on a link inside a sIFR movie, not sure what's up there. The selector looks good, but you might want to try without the transparency.

Wouldn't immediately know how to fix the tab thing either. sIFR is, by nature, hard to make work with tab interfaces. It's not really designed for menus either.

When you use the selector `h2, div:not(.filter) h2` you're replacing *all* `<h2>`s and those not in `div.filter`. Try removing the `h2,` bit and see if that helps.